# Office add-in info doesn't show on task pane for Windows 10 but works on mac

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've got an MS Word Office.js add-in with some task panes.  On the top right of the task pane there is a drop down menu to get info about the add in.

It behaves as expected for Word 2016 on Mac:

[image]

But for Word 2016 on Windows 10, my logo is missing and the "Get Support" link doesn't work:

[image]:

I suspect it is related to my manifest so I'm copying relevant portions below.  Any idea how to fix this for Windows 10?

Things I've tried:

- Clearing the cache in the Wef folder
- Enabling logs in the registry (nothing logged)
- Using Edge Dev Tools.  Here is the console:

[image]

"info" is the HTML source (see [here](https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in/info)).  Looks to not be an actual error.

=====

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>...</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Patent Bots</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Patent Bots GCP"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Patent Bots automated patent proofreading."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_32.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in/redirect/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://gcp.patentbots.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
     <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="File" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        <Set Name="AddinCommands" MinVersion="1.1"/>
     </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadAllDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="PatentBotsTab">
              <Group id="PB.Group">
                <Label resid="PB.Group.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="PB.bot_16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="PB.bot_32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="PB.bot_80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="PB.Info">
                  <Label resid="PB.Info.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="PB.Info.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="PB.Info.Desc"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="PB.bot_16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="PB.bot_32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="PB.bot_80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>PB.Info</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="PB.Info.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="PB.Tab.Label"/>
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_16" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_32" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_80" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="PB.Info.Url" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in/info"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="PB.Group.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots Add In"/>
        <bt:String id="PB.Tab.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots GCP"/>

        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots"/>
        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Title" DefaultValue="Information about Patent Bots"/>    
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Desc" DefaultValue="Information about Patent Bots"/>        
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Can you please load your F12 chooser on windows and check for any console errors. Also if you have office validator installed. Then you can validate your manifest before loading

Comment: @RagavanRajan, I've got the latest updates so my add-in is now running on Edge.  I'll update my question with info from Edge Dev Tools.

Comment: @jeff. cool. Have you validate your manifest ?

Comment: @RagavanRajan, yes with `validate-office-addin` and it passed.

Comment: @jeff. Just a hunch. On your windows once you loaded your addin. Can you hit ctrl + f5 and let me know if that is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem fixed itself without any changes to my add in.  Looks like a bug that Microsoft fixed or maybe a caching issue that eventually resolved itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have played with your manifest

I am on windows 10 Version 1903.

Step 1: Once you loaded your add-in. Hit `Ctrl + F5` on your keyboard to clear the cache on IE. To avoid caching in future add output hashing on your build.

Step 2: Can you try the following manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>7748d238-f27e-5ge1-ab09-5967d67668bg</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Patent Bots</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Patent Bots GCP"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Patent Bots automated patent proofreading."/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_32.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_32.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in/redirect/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://gcp.patentbots.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
     <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
        <Set Name="File" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        <Set Name="AddinCommands" MinVersion="1.1"/>
     </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadAllDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="PatentBotsTab">
              <Group id="PB.Group">
                <Label resid="PB.Group.Label"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="PB.bot_16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="PB.bot_32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="PB.bot_80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="PB.Info">
                  <Label resid="PB.Info.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="PB.Info.Title"/>
                    <Description resid="PB.Info.Desc"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="PB.bot_16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="PB.bot_32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="PB.bot_80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>PB.Info</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="PB.Info.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="PB.Tab.Label"/>
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_16" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_32" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="PB.bot_80" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/static/word-add-in/bot_head_80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="PB.Info.Url" DefaultValue="https://gcp.patentbots.com/word-add-in/info"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="PB.Group.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots Add In"/>
        <bt:String id="PB.Tab.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots GCP"/>

        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Label" DefaultValue="Patent Bots"/>
        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Title" DefaultValue="Information about Patent Bots"/>    
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="PB.Info.Desc" DefaultValue="Information about Patent Bots"/>        
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

**Note:** I have added standalone property on the first element and included the High ResolutionIconURL element

And the output I am getting on my word

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ragavan, did it not work for you before, and doing those changes fixed it?  Those changes don't fix it for me.

Comment: @Jeff. It started working on the first instance. Would you mind sharing your windows build version number

Comment: It fixed itself without the changes in your answer.  Looks like Microsoft fixed a bug somewhere.